# Nodemailer email sent but not received

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, email, nodemailer

I've loked arround the Internet for some solutions people propose, but any of them works for me fe: [this one](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/677) or [this other one](https://github.com/nodemailer/smtp-server/issues/121), even using the example code from [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) website, I get on console

```
Message sent: <c2666ca9-9850-ffce-bcce-8fad0b8f41b8@example.com>
Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/Yxi21TBgBufqRAO3Yxi21mTcOrtHln6cAAAAAXYGM7S1KpoqqzcPthnCZbg
```

But email never arrives.

If it helps, using TypeScript the code I'm using is

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

async function main() {
  let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: testAccount.user,
      pass: testAccount.pass,
    },
  });

  let info = await transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>',
    to: "bepaxeb636@esmoud.com",
    subject: "Hello ✔",
    text: "Hello world?",
    html: "<b>Hello world?</b>",
  });

  console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

  console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

I'm sending the email to a [temporary mail account](https://temp-mail.org/)

Comment: For as far as I know sending a mail using one of the test accounts provided by nodemailer does not actually send the mail. You can preview the email at the given url to see what it will look like. To  send an actual mail you have to create a transport using a real email service.
"Ethereal is a fake SMTP service, mostly aimed at Nodemailer and EmailEngine users (but not limited to). It's a completely free anti-transactional email service where messages never get delivered." - quote from ethereal mail, the service used by nodemailer test accounts.

Comment: Omg, so useless using testAccount and not intuitive to find that Ethereal service never delivers the email... So long being arround with this issue. Thank you a lot @Palladium02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone being arround with this trouble, as said, the Ethereal service used for the testAccount is just a fake service, never delivers any email. Consider using other mail service if you expect the mails to arrive.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is opinion based and should be closed and posted as comment.